# DropDownList in MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, view, controller

I have started a new MVC project with Asp.net
I have a asp:DropDownList component in my Views and this component is bind to the Database , I want get the asp:DropDownList value on my code behind in Controller. Here is my code:

```
string floor = Request.Form["DropDownList1"].ToString();
```

but this string hast null,and I don't know how I can fix this error.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: you need the name parameter that is created when the dropdown list is loaded in the html page in order to obtain its value, for example when you do asp:DDL in your code you can add name="DropDownList1" and you get its value

Comment: `asp:DropDownList` is a server control, try use `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` in code-behind. If you want to use `Request.Form`, you need to use plain HTML `<select>`, or in MVC use `DropDownList`/`DropDownListFor` helper.

Comment: I know that DropDownList is server control , but I can't access to this on my Controller. I think it has some reason such as , my view is  .aspx page , it is not .cshtml ,